# How can I rephrase this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How can I rephrase this sentence?

> Waitlist Me can add the name, phone number and status of customers to
>   indicate with different colors whether the guests are with groups or
>   VIP, ready to be seated or called in.

It seems not very well constructed to me, so I can't get the accurate idea of it.

Comment: is "Waitlist Me" a product name? It would be better to divide the text in 2 sentences, with a second sentence related to status, e.g. "This status uses different colors to indicate whether the guests are with groups or VIP, ready to be seated or called in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posed another good question about food service software today. Here is how it might be rephrased:

**"'Waitlist Me' not only adds the names and phone numbers of guests, but also indicates their status, using color-coded information to determine whether they are still waiting to be seated or called in, and indicating if they are with a group or are considered VIPs, for instance."**

As usual, I agree with Graffito's comment as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. This text is really hard to translate for not a native English speaker

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make it punchier.

*Waitlist Me!* ™ gives the number of guests in the party along with contact name and phone number, and it uses colors to show seating status, such as "VIP" or that the table is now ready.